# ExpressJS session save in cookie

Tags: node.js, session, express, cookies, middleware

I want create session cookie for track user in site. For this purposes I use "express-session" middleware:

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');

app.use(session({
  name: 'cookie',
  secret: 'my express secret',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true,
  cookie: {}
}));
```

But after NodeJS restart cookie loosing. I can't find cookie session storage like as "[Compatible Session Stores](https://github.com/expressjs/session#compatible-session-stores)". I don't want using database to save sessions, I want configure "express-session" to store all data to cookies. Is it possible?

Comment: the session is stored in a cookie, but it refers to the session that is in memory on the server. On the server you need to persist the session if it is to exist across server restarts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cookie-session.

To install: `npm install cookie-session --save`

And include in your app file, for example:

```
var cookieSession = require("cookie-session");

app.use(cookieSession({
    name: "session",
    keys: ["key-1","key-2"]
}));
```